# Magento category description not displaying in list.phtml

Tags: magento

I am creating a custom template for category product view. I am using the catalog/product/list.phtml for this page. The issue is the category title and the description is not displaying.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: The category title and description get displayed from /catalog/category/view.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php 
  $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
  echo $currentCategory->getName();
  echo $currentCategory->getDescription();
?>
```